# add keyup event for dynamically generated buttons in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to define a keyUp event for a List of buttons that I generate dynamically but I can't find the appropriate method to do it.

This is the code that I use to generate the buttons.

```
public void generateurBtns()
    {
        test.cmd.CommandText = "select id from Citoyens";
        test.cmd.Connection = test.cnx;
        test.dr = test.cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (test.dr.Read())
        {
            Button Citoyen = new Button();
            citoyensBtns.Add(Citoyen);
            this.Controls.Add(Citoyen);
            Citoyen.Name = test.dr[0].ToString();
            Citoyen.Click += new EventHandler(button_keyup);
            
        }
        test.dr.Close();
    }
```

I defined the button_keyup method as following.

```
void button_keyup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code executed if button released
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hav you tried `KeyUp` event instead of `Click` ?

```
public void generateurBtns()
{
    test.cmd.CommandText = "select id from Citoyens";
    test.cmd.Connection = test.cnx;
    test.dr = test.cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (test.dr.Read())
    {
        Button Citoyen = new Button();
        citoyensBtns.Add(Citoyen);
        this.Controls.Add(Citoyen);
        Citoyen.Name = test.dr[0].ToString();
        Citoyen.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(button_keyup);
        
    }
    test.dr.Close();
}
```

**update** : you will also need to implement the right delegate:

```
void button_keyup(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //code executed if button released
}
```

Comment: yes i tried it gives me the following error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler'

Comment: i fixed the error by changing the type of event handler to "KeyEventHandler" and now it works fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: @TahaTehitah Ah, the delegate is not the same, see edit